# Appcelerator unable to run app in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, appcelerator

Trying to Run an Alloy app in Studio.

iOS Simulator (iPad 9.2) is launched but the app wont be installed and run. Console shows following logs.

```
[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 4m 4s 404ms
[ERROR] :  An error occurred running the iOS Simulator (ios-sim exit code 1)
2016-01-15T12:24:56.489Z | TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
2016-01-15T12:24:56.490Z | ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/neo/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:92:66)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
2016-01-15T12:24:56.491Z | TRACE  | Sending exit signal to titanium process:  2515
```

The same code-base seems to be running fine on other team members machines.

Checked following based on diff posts but nothing helped:

1. Checked on platform that I am member of the Org -> App
2. Since the project uses 4.0.0.GA, I uninstalled the latest 5.1.2.GA SDK and tried running.

   - XCode v7.2
   - appc v5.1.0
   - Studio v4.4.0...

How to fix/debug this issue?

Comment: how did you run this,please advice am new to Appcelerator

Comment: Upgrade to latest versions of Appc CLI and SDK. I haven't run into these kind of issues with newer versions.

Comment: thank you for your reply.I am very new to titanioum(about 2 weeks).i am using the latest version too.i can run the project via mobile web preview in window.i download ios simulator and unable to connect Appc.please help me your single advice mat turn my task success.

Comment: Maybe post a question here on SO with your relevant exceptions and data and people will help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately iOS Simulator and the CLI it has is like a black box. You mention that you use a relatively old Titanium SDK though, from before the Xcode and iOS versions you target. That might be related. Could you try with a recent (5.1.2) SDK and also make sure it is selected (`appc ti sdk select 5.1.2.GA`)?

Comment: I upgraded back to SDK 5.1.2.GA and am now able to run the app in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it helped me to delete the simulator and re-init it.

The device can be deleted in: Hardware -> Device -> Manage devices in simulator menu